# Checking to see if an element belongs to a parent HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of the format:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                some header stuff
            </td>
            <td>
                header 2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                some info I don't want or need
            </td>
            <td>
                other info I don't want or need
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 real info
            </td>
            <td>
                 real info
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to iterate through all table rows but ignore the tfoot. When I get all elements of tag "tr", I find myself hoping for some function like this.containsParentTag. How would one accomplish this? I cannot find this use case in the JQuery docs for $().filter().

Comment: But you _want_ to see `thead`?

Comment: yeah, I'm exporting to a CSV and I need headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work. You can chain selectors with comma

```
$('thead tr, tbody tr')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can isolate the tbody only:

```
$('tbody tr')
```

Comment: can I get the thead and tbody but not the tfoot?

Comment: You can use something like $('thead tr, tbody tr')

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through "td" value.

$('tbody tr td')